# Inductive kick back

Tags: inductor

[image]

I have simulated two circuits, the switches are open in the beginning and closed and opened after that, because of back EMF the FET has high voltage on VDS for a moment. But one config has 63V as max voltage but the other one is just 6.8V. Why does this happen?

Comment: Where in the circuit is the voltage measured?

Comment: @bobflux Across drain and source, VDS

Comment: You appear to keep using the site like a discussion forum, writing an undetailed question and then discussing further in comments. As it's a Q&A site, please instead write a sufficiently detailed question that shows your own work and researched ideas, ready for an answer to be written without further information from you. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM I'm in a design frenzy please excuse my shortcomings. After answering comments I quickly delve into datasheets and app notes.

Comment: @JAGADISHK - Hi, (a) *Be Nice* - Please read & follow the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct). One of your comments was unkind and has been deleted. Also see the [tour] and [help] for more rules. (b) You may not like feedback from some site members, but you *do* seem to be asking multiple related questions at the same time, and updating them all. This makes it difficult for people to follow updates on other questions, which affect the question *they* are reading. This can annoy people, who feel their time is being wasted when "the goal posts move". Please avoid asking multiple linked questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the plots show Vds.

When the FET turns off, inductor current won't go to zero immediately. Instead, the inductor will increase voltage between its pin until something in the circuit creates a path for current to flow and dissipate the energy stored in the magnetic field.

In both cases, current in the inductor flows left to right, but a different pin on the inductor is switched, and that makes all the difference.

In the left schematic, when the FET turns off, current keeps flowing in the inductor from left to right, which **increases** Vds until the FET avalanches and limits the voltage. Thus you get a large voltage spike.

In the right schematic, when the FET turns off, current also keeps flowing in the inductor from left to right. But the right pin of the inductor is grounded, which means this time the left pin of the inductor drops to a **negative** voltage. Since the FET's gate is biased at 0V through the resistor, it gets enough Vgs to turn, and it does. So its source sets the voltage on the left pin of the inductor (and resistor), and you'll get a few negative volts there.